# Vectorization of growth

Tags: r, loops, vectorization, large-data

I am searching for a solution that implements the following simple growth-rate formula by applying vectorization in R:

```
gr <- function(x){
a <- matrix(,nrow=nrow(x),ncol=ncol(x))
   for (j in 1:ncol(x)){
      for (i in 2:nrow(x)){
        if (!is.na(x[i,j]) & !is.na(x[i-1,j]) & x[i-1,j] != 0){
           result[i,j] <- x[i,j]/x[i-1,j]-1 
        }
       }
    }
return(a)
}
```

I found the xts package to generate lags of time-series, but in the end I always ended up having to compare to many values (see above), so I cannot simply use `ifelse`. One possible problem is when the time-series (e.g. a price index) has zeros in between. This would create `NaNs` in the result, which I am trying to avoid and which cannot simply be removed afterwards (edit: apparently they can, see the answers below!)

In short: I'd like to produce a table of correct growth rates for a given table of values. Here is an example:

```
m <- matrix(c(1:3,NA,2.4,2.8,3.9,0,1,3,0,2,1.3,2,NA,7,3.9,2.4),6,3)
```

generates:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  1.0  3.9  1.3
[2,]  2.0  0.0  2.0
[3,]  3.0  1.0   NA
[4,]   NA  3.0  7.0
[5,]  2.4  0.0  3.9
[6,]  2.8  2.0  2.4
```

correct result, produced by `gr(m)`:

```
           [,1] [,2]       [,3]
[1,]        NA   NA         NA
[2,] 1.0000000   -1  0.5384615
[3,] 0.5000000   NA         NA
[4,]        NA    2         NA
[5,]        NA   -1 -0.4428571
[6,] 0.1666667   NA -0.3846154
```

But this takes forever with large tables. Is there any way to use conditions without looping so extensively?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can speed this up by performing the entire calculation in a single vectorized operation (with one additional operation to fix up the results whenever you divide by 0):

```
out <- rbind(NA, tail(m, -1) / head(m, -1) - 1)
out[!is.finite(out)] <- NA
out
#           [,1] [,2]       [,3]
#             NA   NA         NA
# [2,] 1.0000000   -1  0.5384615
# [3,] 0.5000000   NA         NA
# [4,]        NA    2         NA
# [5,]        NA   -1 -0.4428571
# [6,] 0.1666667   NA -0.3846154
```

This is much faster than a looping solution, as demonstrated on a 1000 x 1000 example:

```
set.seed(144)
m <- matrix(rnorm(10000000), 10000, 1000)
system.time(j <- josilber(m))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   1.425   0.030   1.446 
system.time(g <- gr(m))
#    user  system elapsed 
#  34.551   0.263  36.581
```

The vectorized solution provides a 25x speedup.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple of ways:

**1) no packages**

```
rbind(NA, exp(diff(log(m)))-1)
```

giving:

```
          [,1] [,2]       [,3]
[1,]        NA   NA         NA
[2,] 1.0000000   -1  0.5384615
[3,] 0.5000000  Inf         NA
[4,]        NA    2         NA
[5,]        NA   -1 -0.4428571
[6,] 0.1666667  Inf -0.3846154
```

If it's not important to have a first row of NA then it can be simplified to just `exp(diff(log(m)))-1` .

**2) zoo**  Another way is to use zoo's geomemtric diff function.  Convert to zoo, take geometric differences and subtract 1.  If it's important to have a first row of NAs then merge it back with a zero width series having the original time points (otherwise omit the merge statement and just use `g` as the answer):

```
library(zoo)

zm <- as.zoo(m)
g <- diff(zm, arithmetic = FALSE) - 1
merge(g, zoo(, time(zm))) # omit this line if 1st row of NAs not needed

giving:

        g.1 g.2        g.3
1        NA  NA         NA
2 1.0000000  -1  0.5384615
3 0.5000000 Inf         NA
4        NA   2         NA
5        NA  -1 -0.4428571
6 0.1666667 Inf -0.3846154
```

Comment: thanks, this works as well perfectly! However I'd like to have simple returns and to remove the `Infs`. But from the prev answer I know how to do this now.